# How to call view pager nested fragment method from view pager activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have three tabs in view pager lets say tab1 tab2 and tab3
tab 1 has childfragment
tab 2 has childfragment.

There is one method in tab 1's child fragment which i want to access from the view pager activity.

I am calling tab1 nested fragment method from view pager activity.

```
 NestedFragment fm = (NestedFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.child_scanfragment_container);
```

and calling a method

```
fm.initQR();
```

initQR id the method of nested fragment but Ia m getting null pointer **fm is null.**

Comment: Please describe your question

Comment: get the child fragment from the current fragment of the pager and invoke the method

Comment: @Rustam where should I get that child fragment because I am on the parent activity which contains the viewpager and one tab of view pager has nested fragment and this nested fragment's method i want to call from parent activity.

Comment: child_scanfragment_container this is viewpager's id or frgaent id.

Comment: child fragment's id

Answer (score 0):

child_scanfragment_container
This id must be of view pager's id.
If you are adding fragments in ViewPager than you have to get fragments from ViewPager too.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem..says ClassCastException